# Share folder (fileserver) on local network without passwd Win7

Tags: windows-7, network-shares, shared-folders

We have local network. everyone are on the same switch and there is one computer that is used as a file server.

I created a shared folder on it to be a file server that holds files that other users on the same network wants to store.

Right now we use \file-serve\ from the "run" or desktop icon and then type username&password in order to log in.

Each user can log in and add/remove files (privileges setting are OK).

How can I make it without prompting for password on each time (it remembers the password/username on cache but after a while it prompts again..)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late then never:
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings

In this section of Control Panel, "Network and Sharing Center".. -> "Change advance sharing settings",
the bottom radio button is that one needed to be noticed:

"Password protected sharing" and set radio button to On/Off.